# Android - Thread issues (condition being reached twice) ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

First of all, my code:

```java
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starter_load);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < progressBar.getMax()) {
                progressStatus++;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (progressStatus == 100) {
                    Log.e("download complte", "testing"); // This is being printed twice.
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Here, I'm testing ProgressBar in Android. When it reaches the condition:

```java
if (progressStatus == 100) {...}
```

The log is printed twice in the logcat, and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line and you won't get the second line in log file.

```
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

Actually when you ask android to change the screen orientation, android system recreates your activity and hence creates a new thread while the other thread is still working. This leads to your problem.

If you want your screen orientation to be landscape, try changing it through manifest file under your activity orientation attribute.

Comment: useful link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html